# Pass global variable data to localize_script

Tags: javascript, variables, globals, wp-localize-script

In my template file: `product-list-section.php` I loop through my products and add data to a global variable:

```
global $product_filter_data;
$product_filter_data = array();

// Loop products, grab specific pieces of data and add to $product_filter_data array.
$product_information_system_type = $product_information['product_information_filters']['system_type']['value'];

// Add to $product_filter_data
if( !empty( $product_information_system_type ) ) {
    $product_filter_data[] = $product_information_system_type;
}
```

If I were to var_dump the `$product_filter_data` at this point, it shows data as expected.

Now in my setup.php file, I want to pass that data to `wp_localize_script`.

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    global $product_filter_data;
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    wp_localize_script('custom-js', 'product_filter_data', array('php_product_filter_data' => $product_filter_data));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

```
global $product_filter_data;
var_dump($product_filter_data);

NULL
```

However when I var_dump the variable at this point, it's `NULL`:
`/app/public/wp-content/themes/testtheme/functions/setup.php:22:null`

I'm just unsure why it's NULL. I need to pass that data to JS.

Comment: The enqueue hook runs before the template is loaded so of course the global var is null.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is related to the execution order in WordPress. Global variables in WordPress are request-specific and are not preserved across different requests or different parts of a request unless they are included within the same scope.

The `wp_enqueue_scripts` action runs before the template file is executed, hence your `$product_filter_data` array is still empty when enqueue_scripts is executed.

Here are two potential solutions to the problem:

1. **Use WordPress Transients**: WordPress Transients API can be used to store temporary data that can be retrieved later in the same or a subsequent request. Transients are essentially WordPress Options, but with expiration times.

```
// In your product-list-section.php
set_transient('product_filter_data', $product_filter_data, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS);

// Then, in your setup.php file:
function enqueue_scripts() {
    $product_filter_data = get_transient('product_filter_data');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('custom-js', 'product_filter_data', array('php_product_filter_data' => $product_filter_data));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');
```

2. Use `wp_footer` action: Instead of localizing the script at the time of enqueuing, you can do it at the time of wp_footer action, which occurs after the template file is processed.

```
// Then, in your setup.php file:
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');

function localize_script_in_footer() {
    global $product_filter_data;
    wp_localize_script('custom-js', 'product_filter_data', array('php_product_filter_data' => $product_filter_data));
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'localize_script_in_footer');
```

Remember to replace `custom-js` with the handle of your actual script and replace `product_filter_data` with your data object name. And also, I haven't tested this code. So you may need to do some changes to it so it works properly with your setup.